# Getting the assets prefix twice in img tags with raty in prod. heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the raty jquery library, and my images are broken only in production. This is what I've got in my view:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#target-<%=w_index%>').raty({
            half:  true,
            score: <%= @tastee.try(:jop_rank) || 0 %>,
            starOn: <%= image_path('star-on.png') %>,
            starOff: '<%= image_path('star-off.png') %>',
            starHalf: '<%= image_path('star-half.png') %>',
            cancelOn: '<%= image_path('cancel-on.png') %>',
            cancelOff: '<%= image_path('cancel-off.png') %>'
        });
```

and the rendered result is that the script has the correct url path and hash:

```
starOff: '/assets/star-off-6aaeebdaab93d594c005d366ce0d94fba02e7a07fd03557dbee8482f04a91c22.png'
```

but the rendered image tag has the assets prefix doubled:

```
<img alt="5" src="/assets//assets/star-off-6aaeebdaab93d594c005d366ce0d94fba02e7a07fd03557dbee8482f04a91c22.png" title="gorgeous">
```

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had previously installed and then removed the ratyrate gem.

I removed it from my gem file and from application.js.erb, however the js file was still in present my assets and compiling due to //= require_tree.

Removed the js file, precompiled and redeployed to solve.